# How to send facebook 'app wide' notifications using the PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to send an application wide notification. So that anyone who has authorized your app will receive it?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications#impl

The example they give you assumes you know the users facebook ID?

Is there a way to retrieve all the facebook ids who are currently subscribed? Or will I have to catch all that data as they sign up, store in in a data base and just use a foreach loop to notify every single person.

Much appreciated!

Comment: You have to store them your self. Also be aware that you need to have a minimum number of clicks per view. So sending out notification to everyone is a bad idea.

Comment: Well, if users subscribe to the app it's because they are interested in what I have to say so they should be clicking. But thanks for your reply, after searching through facebook's 'documentation' I was coming to the same conclusion.